# aligning button to bottom within linearlayout parent with minheight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a `LinearLayout` parent which contains two `LinearLayout` child of which second child contains Button which should be place at bottom of the parent view. I'm using `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"` on second child `LinearLayout`

Still I'm getting the output as shown below:[image: Screenshot]

I tried using `RelativeLayout` as a parent but that is making dialog height as big as device screen size which I don't want.

If I remove **minHeight** attribute from `LinearLayout` parent, then parent wraps to height less than minHeight

Any hep appreciated.

Here's my code for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_dialog"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:minWidth="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivDialogImage"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_cfs_activated" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDialogMessage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="80dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btndialogOk"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button_selector"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/alert_ok"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to put the button of second layout at the top of the screen? You can simply put the second layout before the first then the first layout after second.

Comment: Can you show what's your exact requirement?

Comment: Use tablelayout for button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:layout_gravity` defines the gravity for the Layout itself inside it's parent view.

What you should use to apply gravity for child layouts is:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
```

Also, your bottom `LinearLayout` height set to `wrap_content` the button will fit it not matter what you did with the gravity. add a background color to the `LinearLayout` to observe that.

I think what you are looking for, for your bottom layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >
```

This will force your bottom layout to fill the rest of the Parent `LinearLayout`

Answer (score -1):

Here's your answer i have just edited your code change your drawables and colors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivDialogImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cam" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDialogMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivDialogImage"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >


    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btndialogOk"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scan"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="ok"
        android:textColor="@color/red"


        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```